# Tron collision with a generated line in turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I'm doing the last part of my tron game which is to code the collision that happens when the 2nd players' tron bike hits the line of the 1st players tron bike. From there, whoever ran into the line loses, and the other one wins. So my issue is that I'm not 100% sure on how to code this, but I've got an idea and I'm wondering if anyone can help.

What I was thinking was to make myself 4 definitions:

- 1 for the x coordinate of bike 1
- 1 for the y coordinate of bike 1
- 1 for the x coordinate of bike 2
- 1 for the y coordinate of bike 2

In each of these definitions there would be a while loop constantly updating a list with all of the coordinates, kind of like this:

```py
def RedX():
      RedXCordList = [red_player.xcord()]
      while True:
        RedXCordList.append(red_player.xcord())
```

I'm not sure if that's how that works in the first place, but the idea is to get the coordinates into a list/array somehow.

After getting the coordinates into there I'd have to check if one of the bikes positions was equal to any of the coordinates in the list/array, and if it was then there would be a collision. If not the it would continue running until something collided.

Alternatively, Someone can tell me how to detect color and whenever turtle detects the color red or blue it will detect a collision and one will win and one will lose.

I've got barely any clue on how to code that help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my full code if you want to look at it:

```py
def TronGame():
  #Blue Player movements
  def blue_up():  
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'up'
    
  def blue_down():
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'down'
    
  def blue_left():
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'left'
    
  def blue_right():
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'right'

  #Red player Movemnts 
  def red_up():   
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'up'
    
  def red_down():
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'down'
    
  def red_left():
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'left'
    
  def red_right():
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'right'

  #Player movements   
  def move_player(player, direction):
      if direction == 'up':
          player.setheading(90)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'down':
          player.setheading(270)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'left':
          player.setheading(180)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'right':
          player.setheading(0)
          player.forward(5)

  # Helper function to print end of game message
  def game_over(message):
    TurtleCrash = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
    TurtleCrash.color("white")
    style = ('Arial', 25, 'italic')
    TurtleCrash.write(f"{message}\nGame over!", font=style, align='center')

  def collisions():  
    x_blue, y_blue = blue_player.xcor(), blue_player.ycor() 
    x_red, y_red  = red_player.xcor(), red_player.ycor()
    message_turtle =  turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
    message_turtle.color("white")
    collision_text = ""
    if( math.isclose(x_blue, x_red, abs_tol=10.0) and
        math.isclose(y_blue, y_red, abs_tol=10.0)):
      collision_text = "Red and Blue Crashed!\nGame over!"
    if x_blue > width/2 or x_blue < -1*width/2:
      collision_text = "Blue went out of bounds./nRed wins!"
    if y_blue > height/2 or y_blue < -1*height/2:
      collision_text = "Blue went out of bounds./nRed wins!"
    if x_red > width/2 or x_red < -1*width/2:
      collision_text = "Red went out of bounds./nBlue wins!"
    if y_red > height/2 or y_red < -1*height/2:
      collision_text = "Red went out of bounds./nBlue wins!"
    if collision_text: 
        message_turtle.write(collision_text,font=('Arial', 25, 'italic'), align='center')
     
    return False

  def MainTron():
    global screen
    global blue_player
    global red_player
  
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(width, height)
    screen.bgpic('TronBg.png')
    screen.bgcolor('black')
    screen.addshape('BlueBike.gif')
    screen.addshape('RedBike.gif')

    blue_player = turtle.Turtle()
    blue_player.shape('BlueBike.gif')
    blue_player.pencolor("blue")
    blue_player.pensize(3)
    blue_player.pu()
    blue_player.goto(-1*(width)/3, height/8)
    blue_player.pd()

    red_player = turtle.Turtle()
    red_player.shape('RedBike.gif')
    red_player.pencolor("red")
    red_player.pensize(3)
    red_player.pu()
    red_player.goto(width/3, height/8)
    red_player.pd()

    for x in range(5):
      my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
      my_turtle.color("white")
      style = ('Arial', 25, 'italic')
      my_turtle.write(5-x, font=style, align='center') 
      time.sleep(1)
      my_turtle.undo()
  
    screen.listen()
        
    screen.onkey(red_up, "w")
    screen.onkey(red_down, "s")
    screen.onkey(red_left, "a")
    screen.onkey(red_right, "d")
  
    screen.onkey(blue_up, "Up")
    screen.onkey(blue_down, "Down")
    screen.onkey(blue_left, "Left")
    screen.onkey(blue_right, "Right")

    def gameloop():
      move_player(red_player, red_direction)
      move_player(blue_player, blue_direction)
      # Check for a collision. End game if there is one
      if collisions(): 
        return
      #Repeat after 16ms (0.016s) (1000ms/16ms = 62.5 FPS)
      screen.ontimer(gameloop, 16)
    
    screen.ontimer(gameloop, 250)
  
    gameloop()
    screen.mainloop()

  MainTron()

TronGame()
```

Comment: are you familiar with object oriented programing?

Comment: Nope, not too familiar sadly.

Comment: For the entire working code of the game with newest updates check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694075/7711283  .

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking already in the right direction, but still missing the point where to put the code and many other details.

For the entire working code of the game with newest updates check out my answer to your initial question (first in a series of currently three) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694075/7711283 .

There you can see where to put the code for collecting the coordinates and how to evaluate them.