# Trying to add all the coordinates of a turtle into a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So for the last collision of my tron program, I want to record every movement each of my turtles makes into a set. Then I want to compare the set to the current position of the other turtle. How do I make that set?

Something like this:

```py
positions_travelled_red = {(red.xcor(), red.ycor()), etc...)}
positions_travelled_blue = {(blue.xcor(), blue.ycor()), etc...)}
if positions_blue in positions_traveled_red:
    print("Red wins")
```

How do I get all the positions into "positions_travelled_red"?

This is what I tried (and failed):

```py
red_direction = none
blue_direction = none 

positions_traveled_r = {(red_player.xcor(), red_player.ycor())}
    while move_player(red_player, red_direction):
      positions_traveled_r.add((red_player.xcor(), red_player.ycor()))
```

Here is the move players function

```py
def move_player(player, direction):
      if direction == 'up':
          player.setheading(90)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'down':
          player.setheading(270)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'left':
          player.setheading(180)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'right':
          player.setheading(0)
          player.forward(5)
```

In that code above, when I tried printing one of the sets it just gave me the starting position of the turtle and didn't add anything.

Here is my full code if you want to look at it:

```py
def TronGame():
    #Border
    #box = Turtle()
    #box.ht()
    #box.color('purple')
    #box.speed('fastest')
    #box.pensize(10)

   # box.pu()
   # box.goto(-1*height, -1*width)
   # box.pd()

   # for i in range(4):
   #   box.forward(height)
   #   box.left(90)
   #   box.forward(width)
   #   box.left(90)

  
  

  #Blue Player movements
  def blue_up():  
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'up'
    
  def blue_down():
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'down'
    
  def blue_left():
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'left'
    
  def blue_right():
      global blue_direction
      blue_direction = 'right'

  #Red player Movemnts 
  def red_up():   
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'up'
    
  def red_down():
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'down'
    
  def red_left():
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'left'
    
  def red_right():
      global red_direction
      red_direction = 'right'

  #Player movements   
  def move_player(player, direction):
      if direction == 'up':
          player.setheading(90)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'down':
          player.setheading(270)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'left':
          player.setheading(180)
          player.forward(5)
      elif direction == 'right':
          player.setheading(0)
          player.forward(5)

  # Helper function to print end of game message
  def game_over(message):
    TurtleCrash = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
    TurtleCrash.color("white")
    style = ('Arial', 25, 'italic')
    TurtleCrash.write(f"{message}\nGame over!", font=style, align='center')

  def collisions(): 
    global red_player
    global blue_player
    x_blue, y_blue = blue_player.xcor(), blue_player.ycor() 
    x_red, y_red  = red_player.xcor(), red_player.ycor()
    message_turtle =  turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
    message_turtle.color("white")
    collision_text = ""
    if(math.isclose(x_blue, x_red, abs_tol=10.0) and
        math.isclose(y_blue, y_red, abs_tol=10.0)):
      collision_text = "Red and Blue Crashed!\nGame over!"
    if x_blue > width/2 or x_blue < -1*width/2:
      collision_text = "Blue went out of bounds.\nRed wins!"
    if y_blue > height/2 or y_blue < -1*height/2:
      collision_text = "Blue went out of bounds.\nRed wins!"
    if x_red > width/2 or x_red < -1*width/2:
      collision_text = "Red went out of bounds.\nBlue wins!"
      time.sleep(2)
    if y_red > height/2 or y_red < -1*height/2:
      collision_text = "Red went out of bounds.\nBlue wins!"
    if collision_text: 
        message_turtle.write(collision_text,font=('Arial', 25, 'italic'), align='center')

    if blue_player.pos in positions_traveled_r:
      collision_text = "Red wins"
    if red_player.pos in positions_traveled_b:
      collision_text = "Blue wins"
     
    return False

  
  def MainTron():
    global screen
    global blue_player
    global red_player
  
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(width, height)
    screen.bgpic('TronBg.png')
    screen.bgcolor('black')
    screen.addshape('BlueBike.gif')
    screen.addshape('RedBike.gif')

    blue_player = turtle.Turtle()
    blue_player.shape('BlueBike.gif')
    blue_player.pencolor("blue")
    blue_player.pensize(3)
    blue_player.pu()
    blue_player.goto(-1*(width)/3, height/8)
    blue_player.pd()

    red_player = turtle.Turtle()
    red_player.shape('RedBike.gif')
    red_player.pencolor("red")
    red_player.pensize(3)
    red_player.pu()
    red_player.goto(width/3, height/8)
    red_player.pd()

    while True:
      RInstruction = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
      RInstruction.color("red")
      style = ('Arial', 12, 'bold')
      RInstruction.write("↑↓→← to move", font=style, align='Left')
      
      BInstruction = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
      BInstruction.color("blue")
      style = ('Arial', 15, 'bold')
      BInstruction.write("WASD to move", font=style, align='Right')
      break
    
    for x in range(5):
      my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
      my_turtle.color("white")
      style = ('Arial', 25, 'italic')
      my_turtle.write(5-x, font=style, align='center') 
      time.sleep(1)
      my_turtle.undo()
  
    screen.listen()
        
    screen.onkey(red_up, "Up")
    screen.onkey(red_down, "Down")
    screen.onkey(red_left, "Left")
    screen.onkey(red_right, "Right")
  
    screen.onkey(blue_up, "w")
    screen.onkey(blue_down, "s")
    screen.onkey(blue_left, "a")
    screen.onkey(blue_right, "d")

    def gameloop():
      move_player(red_player, red_direction)
      move_player(blue_player, blue_direction)
      # Check for a collision. End game if there is one
      if collisions(): 
        return
      #Repeat after 16ms (0.016s) (1000ms/16ms = 62.5 FPS)
      screen.ontimer(gameloop, 16)
    
    screen.ontimer(gameloop, 250)
  
    gameloop()
    screen.mainloop()

  MainTron()
TronGame()
```

Comment: For the entire working code of the game with newest updates (also to the in the answer provided code snippet) check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694075/7711283  .

Answer (score 0):

Your code around the set looks correct.

Your mistake lies in `while move_player(red_player, red_direction):`, as this will only run as long as `move_player` returns something truthy.

By default functions return `None`, which is falsey, so your loop runs 0 times. (but move_player still gets executed once for the first boolean check)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to experience collision detection you intend to achieve in action add to your code following snippet:

```
red_clones  = []
blue_clones = []
def check_collisions():
    global red_clones, blue_clones
    msg = "" # will be used as flag indicating collision
    rpc = red_player.clone();  rpc.hideturtle()
    bpc = blue_player.clone(); bpc.hideturtle()
    red_clones.append( rpc );  blue_clones.append( bpc )
    for red_clone in red_clones: 
        if blue_player.distance(red_clone) < PLAYER_MIN_DISTANCE:
            msg = "Blue crashed in Red's path.\nRed wins!"
    for blue_clone in blue_clones:
        if red_player.distance(blue_clone) < PLAYER_MIN_DISTANCE:
            msg = "Red crashed in Blue's path.\nBlue wins!"
    if( blue_player.distance(red_player) < PLAYER_MIN_DISTANCE ): 
        msg = "Red and Blue Crashed!\nGame over!"
```

**That's it.**

Now that you can see how it works you can go over to the next step and modify the provided solution in a way that the code runs faster and needs less computing power.